# Optimizing code for searching a text in richtextbox windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a windows form application that use a `RichTextBox` to display a text from a file. There is also a `TextBox` and a `Button` to perform a search in the text. Whenever the button is clicked, the content of the `TextBox` is searched and enlightened in the `RichTextBox`. Here is the code in the `button_Click` event handler:

```
String search = richtextboxContent.Text;
richtextboxContent.Text = "";
richtextboxContent.Text = search;

#region code Search
string keyword = textboxsearch.Text.Trim();
int startPosition = 0;
int endPosition = 0;
int endArticle = richtextboxContent.Text.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < endArticle; i = startPosition)
{
    if (i == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    startPosition = richtextboxContent.Find(keyword, startPosition, endArticle, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    if (startPosition >= 0)
    {
        count++;
        richtextboxContent.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
        endPosition = textboxsearch.Text.Length;
        startPosition = startPosition + endPosition;
    }
}
```

I have one text file of 20mb with 90.000++ lines, whenever I search one word (that resulted with 1300 matchs) the code below take more than 10 minutes to finish.

How can it be improved ?

Comment: Don't use the `RichTextBox.Find()` + `RichTextBox.SelectionBackColor` (you generate a whole lot of messages that go into message pump and need to be processed before the next string is searched) method. Use `Regex.Matches()`, targeting the source file, not the RTB text. Each `Match` contains the position and length of the string found. You can then use these values to select specific parts of the text in the RTB in one go.

Comment: Does that mean i need to replace my richtextbox into textbox control to use Regex.Matches() method ? or Regex.Matches() can be used for richtextbox control?

Comment: Don't use the RichTextBox directly: use the source file or a string containing that text.

Comment: I already have this code to contain all the text from my .txt file into my richtextbox 
   string textToContent = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
   richtextboxContent.Text = textToContent;

do i need to contain all the .txt words into another string, and transfer to richtextbox on form_load?

Comment: @RKDev you question title is about optimizing code for searching, but you write that the loading time of the application is huge (>10mn). Once the application is loaded does the search take a lot of time ? Do you want to improve the loading time or the search time ?

Comment: @Jimi, is it possible to made a multi-part selection and perform only one `SelectionBackColor` that will en-light all results ? Can you provide some link ?

Comment: @Orace sorry for misleading the title, i want to improve my app's loading time whenever i click the Search button.

Comment: @RKDev, the loading time is the time the app take to load (to start and be usable). You can't click the search button if the app is not loaded. Again, what is slow : the startup (loading) or the search ?

Comment: Pass the string to [Regex.Matches](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches), using the `(string Source, string Pattern)` overload, to start from position `0`. Where `Source` is the `RichTextBox.Text` value or the `textToContent` content (it depends on the linefeed type of the source file: if `\r\n`, the RTB converts it to `\n`, so you strip `\r` yourself or let the RTB do it) and `Pattern` is the string you're looking for (separate multiple words with a pipe). Then you use the RichTextBox methods to highligh the text using the each Match values.

Comment: [This is a VB.Net version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53680758/7444103) that you can easily translate to C#.

Comment: @Orace i have no problem with the loading time of my application (start), but whenever i click the search button (contains code above from my post) to match the string in RTB and textbox, the apps need a very long time to show the output.

Comment: @Jimi thank you very much sir, will find out the code from the link asap. i'll comment it later for the result.

Comment: @Jimi It worked very well with regex, cut the loading time from 10 min to 1.15 min.If you don't mind, do you have others example to show line number from the match words using regex ? anyway, Thank you very much sir

Comment: [RichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex) returns the current logical line in the RTB, corresponding to each `Match.Index` (the char position). Btw, `75` seconds for a `20 Mb` text file is too much. It should take a few seconds (maybe 10). You probably have something else there that slows it down. For example, never (ever) use the `Lines` property in a loop. Compile the Regex, as shown in the example. And don't do this: `richtextboxContent.Text = ""; richtextboxContent.Text = search;`.

Comment: Also, see that you have the `HideSelection` property set to `true` (in case it's not). Otherwise the RTB will auto scroll and this is also slow)

Comment: @Jimi Thank you sir, will try it asap for the Line position.
Does writing richtextboxContent.Text = ""; richtextboxContent.Text = search; make the app slower ?? i wrote that to make sure whenever i clicked my Search button for second,third... times, it remove the highlighted text from first or (n-1) search result.

Comment: `richTextBox1.SelectAll(); richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = richTextBox1.BackColor;`