# Why doesn't find function work in While statment

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm using a RichTextBox find function. It works fine until I stick it in a While loop. Then it won't do anything.

This code works:

```
Dim startTEXT As Integer = 0
Dim endTEXT As Integer = RichTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(tword)
While startTEXT < endTEXT
    RichTextBox1.Find(tword, startTEXT, RichTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
    RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font(RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.FontFamily, RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Size, FontStyle.Underline)
    RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
    startTEXT = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(tword, startTEXT) + 1
End While
```

This code does not:

```
For Each tword In ListBox1.Items
     Dim startTEXT As Integer = 0
     Dim endTEXT As Integer = RichTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(tword)
     While startTEXT < endTEXT
        RichTextBox1.Find(tword, startTEXT, RichTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
        RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font(RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.FontFamily, RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Size, FontStyle.Underline)
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
        startTEXT = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(tword, startTEXT) + 1
    End While
Next
```

What is preventing the find function from working?
Using VB.NET 2010.

Comment: Are you sure that Find doesn't work, or is it that the early iterations are overwritten by the later ones?

Comment: First thing, set `Option Strict On`, then declare the Font outside the loops as, e.g., `dim selFont = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Underline)` and set it either in the loop or outside the loop: `RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = selFont` (since it appears the Font doesn't change, you can set it once right after you have declared it, outside the loops) -- You may want to replace this procedure with something like this: [Why can't I change the color of repeated words in a RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53680758/7444103), it's much easier to handle (and debug).

Comment: As a note, if you're actually using Visual Studio 2010, you should (really) consider updating it (if it's up to you, of course). [Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) is free software.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.items?view=netframework-4.8) ListBox.Items, is a [ListBox.ObjectCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection?view=netframework-4.8).  Should `tword` be an `Object` or a `String`? How do you convert an Object to a String?

Comment: The `Find` function works fine if it's by itself in the `If` or the `While` statement. It just doesn't work when it's in the `If` and the `While` statement.

Comment: @Jimi Setting the font outside the loops didn't fix it. Also, I'm using 2010 because my computer is very old and won't connect to the internet anymore. (currently using a secondary Linux device for internet) I want to switch to Python at some point (as I can program a bit) but my laptop also doesn't work with Python, for some odd reason. Also don't think the Regex will work in my case.

Comment: The Font thing is about optimization, the important part is that you set `Option Strict On` (the very first thing I mentioned). Then fix the problem that it's going to become clear. -- The Regex of course works, since it's actually doing the same thing, just more efficiently (and, also mentioned, it's easier to debug, because you don't need two nested loops anymore).

Comment: @Jimi I guess I could try again but the `Option Strict On` isn't really going to help. As I said, the `Find` function works fine with the `tword` so that can't be the issue. It's just the combination of the `If` and the `While` loop together that make it not work. By themselves they work flawlessly. I'll have to look into the Regex as I've never used it before, but it doesn't look like it will work.

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`. That's not really an *option*, it's a necessity. That option set to `OFF` is meant to ease the port of VB6 app to VB.Net and exists for this reason only. In a VB.Net app, this is just trouble and trickery and source of problems hard to debug, not mentioning *unexplicable* run-time exceptions and misbehaviors. The fact that some people abuse it is not an excuse for anyone.

Comment: @Jimi Set `Option Strict On` fixed the few errors and still `Find` function isn't working.

Comment: Well, now (if you actually fixed the *right* problems) you have properly working code. Code that works, when fixed, because I've tested it. If it still doesn't work for you, you have omitted details on when / where / how that code is used. Or, trivial, the Controls you're using are not the right ones. -- Give some context to code you've posted. Also, have you actually debugged it (setting breakpoints, following the flow, inspecting the content / values of variable etc.)?

Comment: @Jimi Only thing I needed to change was `tword` to `tword.ToString()`. There's not much more context other than what's in the code. I'm just going through all the items in a ListBox and coloring where they appear in a RichTextBox. Yes, I've debugged it. There should be no reason it doesn't work, must just be something wrong with VB.Net.

Comment: What are the values returned by `tword.ToString()`, in the loop? Is the content of the RTB what is expected? What calls this code? When it's called? Do you simply have this code in, e.g., a Button.Click handler? Or something else? -- Again, I've tested it. It works. You don't have some form of threading there, right? Is that the actual code you have, or did you change something when posting it here? If that's the case, you need to post the actual code

Comment: @Jimi No that's the actual code, didn't change it. It runs when a button is clicked. The value returned by `tword.ToString()` is what it should be, no issue there. Did you test with 2010 or a later version? Maybe it's just a bug with the 2010 version.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022. Doesn't matter, this functionality is not part of the Language itself, it's part of the Framework, since .Net Fx 1.1 -- Test the Regex thing I've posted earlier, see how that works. If it doesn't, the real problem is somewhere else. In VB.Net, this usually happens because one is using default instances of Forms.  Or because you create a ne instance of a Form in another class, trying to get the reference of Controls contained in the instance shown on screen.

Comment: Also consider that this search is case sensitive.

Comment: @Jimi Tested Regex, it didn't work. There's no Regex option like the Find option `WholeWord` so it would detect things like "is" in the middle of words not just the word itself.

Comment: Did figure out the problem though. `WholeWord` isn't case sensitive, but I failed to remember that `LastIndexOf` is, so I was basically nullifying my find function. I did eventually find a way to fix it though, so now it's working as it should.

Comment: *There's no Regex option like the Find option WholeWord*: are you kidding me? The equivalent is `\b`, as in: `dim pattern = String.Concat(ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).Select(Function(w) "\b" & w & "\b|"))`. As you can see,  `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is already set in that code, as a Regex Option. But this can be set with a token, too. -- The method above uses LINQ's `Select()`, which is usually imported by default. If it's not, add `Imports System.Linq`. But you can build the `pattern` string with a standard loop instead. With a Regex, the search procedure can become **very** flexible.

Comment: @Jimi Ok, but is Regex actually significantly faster enough that I should bother trying to get it working?

Comment: *Faster* in what context? A large amount of text? A large number of different words to search? A combination of both? In what .Net version? In .Net 5+, the Regex class has been optimized quite a lot. But you cannot target these new .Net platforms. Is it faster than something else in specific conditions? You have to time it.

Comment: @Jimi Just as a general rule, is it faster. I don't see that Regex is a big enough deal to change anything with my current project, however I may use it in future projects (especially if I need to use complex formulas).